# Working with Microsoft Sync Framework and SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to use Microsoft Sync framework with SQL Server 2000?

I tried, one way is working fine... from server to client. Bidirectional is not working. Changes made on the client are not updated to server.

Please let me know if there is any changes need to be done on server side to make it work.

Thanks Karthik

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Sync Framework on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281959%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> *Sync Services for ADO.NET supports databases in the following ways:*
>
> *In offline scenarios, the client database must be SQL Server Compact 3.5 version 3.5 or later. The server can be any database for
>   which an ADO.NET provider is available.*
>
> *In collaborative scenarios, each peer database must be **SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4** or a later version.*

So: do you have SP4 for SQL Server 2000 installed?

Comment: Marc, Im using for offline scenario where there is 1 client and 1 central server.Im working with SQL 2000 service pack 2.Im not getting any error but changes are not updated back to Server.I used the Local Database Cache Wizard and changed the syncdirection to bidirectional.

Comment: @karthik: I'd suggest you apply **SP 4** and see if that indeed solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

am assuming you used the Local Database Cache Wizard and you simply change the sync direciton to Bidirectional...

its not enough to just change the sync direction...try the steps here: [Walkthrough: Extending the Local Database Cache to Support Bidirectional Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761546.aspx)

Comment: MArc_S and JuneT Thanks for Your reply. JUNE t yes i used the wizard and changed the sysn direction to bidirectional.Same thing worked for SQL 2008. Thanks for the link i will try it.